# Use NSTimeInterval to trigger notification in WatchOS2

Tags: ios, swift, countdown, watchos-2, nstimeinterval

I am trying to make a pomodoro app on the Apple Watch (OS2). I want to trigger a notification after the countdown is finished, in the first step I am trying to print some word in console, but it still does not works. How to use `NSTimeInterval` to get the remaining time to do that?

```
  import WatchKit
  import Foundation


  class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

let countdown:NSTimeInterval = 1501

var timerRunning = false

@IBOutlet var pauseButton: WKInterfaceButton!

@IBOutlet var timer: WKInterfaceTimer!

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)
}

override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    super.didDeactivate()
}

@IBAction func startPomodoro() {

    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: countdown)
    timer.setDate(date)
    timer.start();
    WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Start)
    WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Start)
}


@IBAction func resetPomodoroTimer() {
    timer.stop()
    let resetCountdown:NSTimeInterval = 1501
    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: resetCountdown)

    timer.setDate(date)
    WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Retry)
    WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Retry)
}


@IBAction func pausePomodoro() {
    timer.stop()

    if !timerRunning{
        pauseButton.setTitle("Restart")
    }
    WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Stop)
    WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Stop)
}

func showNotification(){

    if countdown < 1490
    {
        print("Notification")
        WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Success)
        WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Success)
    }
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger a notification after the `WKInterfaceTimer` has finished you have to add a `NSTimer` with the same time interval. You start both at the same time and when the NSTimer fires you know that the WKInterfaceTimer also finished. IMHO that is not a very elegant solution, but it is suggested in Apple's documentation, so there's apparently is no other way to do this.

If you want to add a pause / restart functionality you have to track the remaining time when the user hits "pause" and stop both timers. When the user starts the timer again, you set both timers to the remaining time and start them.

Here is a working example with pause / restart functionality (it has a WKInterfaceButton that is connected to the `button` outlet and the `didPressButton:` action:

```
enum TimerState {
    case Idle, Running, Paused, Finished
}

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    let countdownDuration: NSTimeInterval = 10
    var remainingDuration: NSTimeInterval = 10
    var timer: NSTimer?
    var timerState = TimerState.Idle

    @IBOutlet var interfaceTimer: WKInterfaceTimer!
    @IBOutlet var button: WKInterfaceButton!

    @IBAction func didPressButton() {

        switch timerState {
        case .Idle:
            startTimer(remainingDuration: countdownDuration)
        case .Running:
            let fireDate = timer!.fireDate
            remainingDuration = fireDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(NSDate())
            interfaceTimer.stop()
            timer?.invalidate()
            button.setTitle("Continue")
            timerState = .Paused
        case .Paused:
            startTimer(remainingDuration: remainingDuration)
        case .Finished:
            break
        }
    }

    func startTimer(remainingDuration duration:NSTimeInterval) {
        interfaceTimer.setDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: duration))
        interfaceTimer.start()
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(duration, target: self, selector: Selector("timerDidFire:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        button.setTitle("Pause")
        timerState = .Running
    }

    func timerDidFire(timer: NSTimer) {
        interfaceTimer.stop()
        timerState = .Finished
        WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Success)
    }
}
```